# How to change styles for ui-datetimepicker

Tags: css, datepicker

I have added 2 date pickers for two input fields in my page.One is `datepicker()` and another one is `datetimepicker()`.
`datepicker()` is displaying correctly but `datetimepicker()` is displaying over the text box.So textbox is getting hided.So I have decided to display the `datetimepicker()` beside to the textbox.

I added this css:

```
.ui-datepicker{
left: 454px !important;
}
```

But both `datepicker()` and `datetimepicker()` position got changed.I want to change only the position of `datetimepicker()`.
How to do it?Is it possible to add dynamic class for `datetimepicker()` to apply css?

Comment: can you provide your code?

Comment: You'll want to change the class of the datetimepicker() to something like `ui-datetimepicker` and then have a separate style for that class.

Comment: @SchoolBoy How will you add dynamic class for `datetimepicker`?

Comment: `$("#ui-datepicker-div").removeClass("ui-datepicker");`

`$("#ui-datepicker-div").addClass("ui-datetimepicker");`

Comment: Or something along those lines anyway, I haven't used datetimepicker much

Comment: @SchoolBoy  ok thanks.I will try.